/usr/bin/ld: cannot find /libQt5Multimedia.so: No such file or directory
A Qt5 program called leterrier-calculmental can't be compiled and packaged on Linux Mint 21.3 because of the folowing error:
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find /libQt5MultimediaWidgets.so: No such file or directory
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find /libQt5Multimedia.so: No such file or directory

Somehow, when it configures the sources to compile, it does not correctly locate Qt5Multimedia and Qt5MultimediaWidgets. If I correct the last line, it compiles flawlessly, I just change "/libQt5MultimediaWidgets.so" to "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Multimedia.so.5" and
leterrier-calculment.pro contains: (not only)
+= widgets multimedia multimediawidgets

src/Makefile contains (not only):
LIBS          = $(SUBLIBS) -lz -lexiv2 -lQt5Multimedia -lQt5MultimediaWidgets /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Multimedia.so -L/usr/lib/ -lttspico -logg -lvorbis -lvorbisenc -lvorbisfile /libQt5MultimediaWidgets.so /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Svg.so /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5PrintSupport.so /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Widgets.so /libQt5Multimedia.so /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Gui.so /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Script.so /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Network.so /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Xml.so /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Core.so -lGL -lpthread

Here, the mistake is clean, but when does it incorrectly indicate multimedia lib's path as "/"?
The problematic command is:
/usr/lib/qt5/bin/qmake -o Makefile src.pro 'QMAKE_CC = cc' 'QMAKE_CXX = g++' 'QMAKE_CFLAGS_RELEASE = -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -O3' 'QMAKE_CXXFLAGS_RELEASE = -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -O3' 'QMAKE_LFLAGS_RELEASE = -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -flto=auto -ffat-lto-objects -flto=auto -Wl,-z,relro'

The original src.pro is:
# -------------------------------------------------
# Project created by QtCreator 2010-07-13T16:03:17
# -------------------------------------------------
system(ccache -V):QMAKE_CXX = ccache g++

QT += script network xml gui widgets multimedia multimediawidgets

TARGET = leterrier-calculment
TEMPLATE = app

SOURCES += main.cpp \
    interface.cpp \
    baudruche.cpp \
    boutonspolygone.cpp \
    sauvegardelog.cpp \
    editeur.cpp \
    abuledulanceurv1.cpp \
    exercicemaisonnombres.cpp \
    pixmapmaison.cpp \
    abuledulineeditv0.cpp \
    futurelib/abuleduexportpdfv1/abuleduexportpdfv1.cpp \
    calculmentgraphicsview.cpp \
    abstractexercise.cpp \
    exerciceoperation.cpp \
    abuledupixmapwidgetv1.cpp

HEADERS += interface.h \
    baudruche.h \
    boutonspolygone.h \
    sauvegardelog.h \
    editeur.h \
    abuledulanceurv1.h \
    exercicemaisonnombres.h \
    pixmapmaison.h \
    version.h \
    abuledulineeditv0.h \
    futurelib/abuleduexportpdfv1/abuleduexportpdfv1.h \
    calculmentgraphicsview.h \
    leterrierstringtransition.h \
    abstractexercise.h \
    exerciceoperation.h \
    abuledupixmapwidgetv1.h

FORMS += interface.ui \
    editeur.ui \
    abuledulanceurv1.ui

RESOURCES += \
    calculment.qrc \
    abuledupixmapwidgetv1.qrc

win32{
  OTHER_FILES += ../windows/windows.rc
  RC_FILE = ../windows/windows.rc
}

macx {
 ICON = ../macos/icones/leterrier-calculment.icns
}


include(lib/abuleduapplicationv1/abuleduapplicationv1.pri)
include(lib/abuleduconstantesv1/abuleduconstantesv1.pri)
include(lib/abuledunetworkaccessmanagerv1/abuledunetworkaccessmanagerv1.pri)
include(lib/abuledumessageboxv1/abuledumessageboxv1.pri)
include(lib/abuleduidentitesv1/abuleduidentitesv1.pri)
include(lib/abuleduflatboutonv1/abuleduflatboutonv1.pri)
include(lib/maia/maia.pri)
include(lib/abuleduexercicev1/abuleduexercicev1.pri)
include(lib/abuledusplashscreenv1/abuledusplashscreenv1.pri)
include(lib/abuledufilev1/abuledufilev1.pri)
include(lib/abuledusingletonv1/abuledusingletonv1.pri)
include(lib/abuledupluginloaderv1/abuledupluginloaderv1.pri)
include(lib/abuledulangv1/abuledulangv1.pri)
include(lib/abuleduloggerv1/abuleduloggerv1.pri)
include(lib/abuleduloadinganimationv1/abuleduloadinganimationv1.pri)
include(lib/abuleduaproposv1/abuleduaproposv1.pri)
include(lib/abuledustackedwidgetv1/abuledustackedwidgetv1.pri)
include(lib/abuledumultimediav1/abuledumultimediav1.pri)
include(lib/abuledupicottsv1/abuledupicottsv1.pri)
include(lib/abuleduaudiov1/abuleduaudiov1.pri)
include(lib/abuledupageaccueilv1/abuledupageaccueilv1.pri)
include(lib/abuledugraphicmenuv1/abuledugraphicmenuv1.pri)
include(lib/abuledulabelv1/abuledulabelv1.pri)
include(lib/abuleducommonstatesv1/abuleducommonstatesv1.pri)
include(lib/abuledustatemachinev1/abuledustatemachinev1.pri)
include(lib/abuledutetev1/abuledutetev1.pri)
include(lib/abuleduetiquettesv1/abuleduetiquettesv1.pri)
include(lib/abuledunumericlinearpadv1/abuledunumericlinearpadv1.pri)

The generated Makefile is (only relevant part):
[...]
LIBS          = $(SUBLIBS) -lz -lexiv2 -lQt5Multimedia -lQt5MultimediaWidgets /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Multimedia.so -L/usr/lib/ -lttspico -logg -lvorbis -lvorbisenc -lvorbisfile /libQt5MultimediaWidgets.so /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Svg.so /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5PrintSupport.so /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Widgets.so /libQt5Multimedia.so /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Gui.so /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Script.so /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Network.so /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Xml.so /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Core.so -lGL -lpthread
[...]

Added: the output of qmake -d

There is probably some variable in some config script that is not set. Something like $(SOMEVAR)/ibQt5MultimediaWidgets.so expands to /libQt5MultimediaWidgets.so. It is a bug in the library, file it.

How can I guess what is the affected variable and spot the problem? I use Linux Mint 21.3, that is, Ubuntu 22.04 LTS. It's quite stable, and this error is weird.

No idea, need to read the scripts and/or the logs.

I have set up an Ubuntu 24.04 chroot and it gives exactly the same error, can we discard an upstream bug?

Do you have the same issue if you just use plain qmake without any option ? If so, I would change the various XXXFLAGSXXX = with XXXFLAGSXXX +=.

I have executed qmake alone (and the complete qmake with options exactly the same as in the make script) and the error remains exactly the same.

I have executed (and no luck): /usr/lib/qt5/bin/qmake -o Makefile src.pro 'QMAKE_CC = cc' 'QMAKE_CXX = g++' 'QMAKE_CFLAGS_RELEASE += -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -O3' 'QMAKE_CXXFLAGS_RELEASE += -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -O3' 'QMAKE_LFLAGS_RELEASE += -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -flto=auto -ffat-lto-objects -flto=auto -Wl,-z,relro'
